# Run-time error when creating a named range based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that goes through a table. When it finds the word "Reporting" in column C and "OSI" in column B, it creates a range called "OSIRep" going from column D-E-F for every row where the criteria in column B and C are true.

However, when I change the word to "Security" and "OSI" to create a range "OSISec", I get an error and I don't know why. The error is 'Run-Time error 1004 - Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed' and this occurs on sht.Range(sRng)

The range it is searching through is no different, the name I am trying to create doesn't already exist and my criteria are present. Any ideas?

I have tried taking an protections of the worksheet, unlocking cells and exploring the error code, all to no avail.

Thank you in advance for any help or insight you can provide!

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Features")

Set featuresRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("B1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
rngArray = featuresRng
ReDim NewArr(1 To 1)
y = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(rngArray)
    If rngArray(i, 2) = "Reporting" And rngArray(i, 1) = "OSI" Then
        ReDim Preserve NewArr(1 To y)
        NewArr(y) = featuresRng.Rows(i).Resize(1, 3).Offset(0, 2).Address
        y = y + 1

    End If
Next i

sRng = Join(NewArr, Application.DecimalSeparator)
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "OSIRep", sht.Range(sRng)
```

Comment: How long is `sRng` at that point? Range is limited to 255 characters for the address.

Comment: I think you're right - it is the characters that is the issue. When I try and add in 'Security', the range I will be referring to is three lines rather than just one for Reporting. Is there a solution for this you could suggest for larger ranges?

Comment: Instead of building up an address string, create a range object (using `Union`) and then name it at the end.

Comment: Hi @Rory thanks for the suggestion. I have looked up the Union function but still not sure how to use it, can you show me how I would implement it into my code?

Comment: @PKen, check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, `Range` only accepts a 255 character address string, so you may be better off dealing with an actual Range object as you loop:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(rngArray)
    If rngArray(i, 2) = "Reporting" And rngArray(i, 1) = "OSI" Then
         Dim OutputRange As Range
         If OutputRange Is Nothing Then
            Set OutputRange = featuresRng.Rows(i).Resize(1, 3).Offset(0, 2)
         Else
            Set OutputRange = Union(OutputRange, featuresRng.Rows(i).Resize(1, 3).Offset(0, 2))
         End If
    End If
Next i

If Not OutputRange Is Nothing Then OutputRange.Name = "OSIRep"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `featuresRng` object as you can address the worksheet directly since you know the columns you are dealing with before hand. Here is an efficient method to achieve your goal:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim sht As Worksheet, MySel As Range, rngArray As Variant, i As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Features")

With sht
    rngArray = .Range("B1", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(rngArray)
        If rngArray(i, 2) = "Reporting" And rngArray(i, 1) = "OSI" Then
            If MySel Is Nothing Then
                Set MySel = .Range("D" & i & ":F" & i)
            Else
                Set MySel = Application.Union(MySel, .Range("D" & i & ":F" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

If Not MySel Is Nothing Then MySel.Name = "OSIRep"
'Set MySel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @AAA, thank you for your reply!! This worked so well. However, if I want to do another selection say "Filter" and "OSI", it adds the previous range onto my new range. How do I avoid this?

Comment: @PKen, are you doing this in this same Macro? If so, after the last line of the code add this: `Set MySel = Nothing`